# mariadb explain filter=100 even though the correct index is selected

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting horrible performance on a very simple query:

explain select count(*) from `call_details_raw` where `PNBLSTimeOn` between '2019-03-10 02:15:00' and '2019-03-10 02:20:00'

```
+------+-------------+------------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table            | type  | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra                    |
+------+-------------+------------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | call_details_raw | index | PNBLSTimeOn   | PNBLSTimeOn | 5       | NULL | 7566362 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
+------+-------------+------------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
```

mysql is taking a very long time to tell me that the result is 0:

```
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (4.68 sec)
```

It says it's using the correct index, but filter=100 which means it's analyzing every row in table anyway.

Here's the full table definition if it helps:

```
CREATE TABLE `call_details_raw` (
  `call_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PNBLSPrimaryCSN` char(16) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSBillingAccount` char(16) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSMainAccount` char(16) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSXferAccount` char(16) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSTimeOn` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSTimeOff` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSNumberDialed` char(20) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSANI` char(20) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSTotalTime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSRingTime` decimal(11,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSHoldTime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSQueueTime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSInboundTime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSInboundCall` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSOutboundTime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSOutboundCall` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSCheckinTime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSCheckinCall` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSVMTime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSVMCall` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSPagerTime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSPagercall` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSConfTime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSConfCall` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSConfParties` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSConfSetupTime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSAppDialouts` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSAlphaPages` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSFaxes` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSEmails` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSMsgsSaved` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSNoMsgs` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSWorkTime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSMLTime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSLiveRecTime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSLiveRecCall` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSSATime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSInEmails` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSConfSetups` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSAgentConfTime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSParkTime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSFlashOverTrunk` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSAutoDigCalls` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSAutoDigTime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSMsgTime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSMsgEditTime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSMsgTimeSusp` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSMsgEditTimeSusp` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSWorkTimeSusp` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSMsgListSusp` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSSATimeSusp` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSPreAnnounceCall` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSPreAnnounceTime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSAbandonedCall` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSWrapTime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSLastAgent` char(16) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSLastAgentName` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSLocates` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSLocateTime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSSMSIn` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSSMSOut` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSPF2Fax` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSPF2FaxTime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSPF2FaxPages` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSPPSPage` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSPPSPageTime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSQueueDrop` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSPreAnnDrop` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSMsgInsAPI` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSOrderNum` char(16) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSSecMsgIn` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSSecMsgOut` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNBLSSecMsgRead` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`call_id`),
  KEY `PNBLSTimeOn` (`PNBLSTimeOn`),
  KEY `PNBLSTimeOff` (`PNBLSTimeOff`),
  KEY `PNBLSInboundCall` (`PNBLSInboundCall`),
  KEY `PNBLSLastAgent` (`PNBLSLastAgent`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7994796 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

```
select @@version;
10.1.30-MariaDB
```

Comment: Well the MySQL/MariaDB optimizer thinks it's needs to search a estimate of 7566362 records to give a answer on your query, i assume you do bulk inserts/updates on this table?

Comment: *"It says it's using the correct index, but filter=100 which means it's analyzing every row in table anyway."* actually when looking into your explain plan the optimizer is using a covering index which means the index file is read only the table file is never readed.

Comment: I suggest you to deploy [Partitioning](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/partitioning-overview/#uses-for-partitioning) and use the RANGE/LIst partitions as [Partitioning Type](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/partitioning-types/) .. Also i would suggest using [subpartitions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/range-columns-and-list-columns-partitioning-types/) on year - month.

Comment: .. If MariaDB optimizer is as good as MySQL's optimizer i assume it can use [Partition Pruning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-pruning.html) it only read the partitions where the data might be, but the MariaDB docs are not mentioning this.. Edit MariaDB can also do [Partition Pruning](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/partition-pruning-and-selection/)

Comment: @RaymondNijland I do bulk inserts but not updates. This is a copy of a table from another database for doing statistical analysis.

Comment: ok try running `ANALYZE TABLE` after every bulk insert, keep in mind it will lock the table with a read lock.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I have another database running MySQL 5.5 on Ubuntu 14 with 32M rows and a near identical table structure except it has more columns and uses latin1 instead of utf8. the same select count(*) returns instantly. This problematic MariaDB is from xampp and running on Windows in AWS. Could any of those be a contributing problem?

Comment: And the 4.68s implies that it is spending a lot more time that it should.  I used to see this often when the result was `0`.  File a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

Debian 9 plus the current default 10.1.38-MariaDB-0+deb9u1 fixed the problem.

Same AWS hosting, same resource allocation of cpu, memory and storage iops.

Could be a bug in 10.1.30 that's fixed in 10.1.38 but it's equally possible that there's a configuration problem in how it's distributed with xampp.

I'm not inclined to dig further, but in case someone else runs into some bizarre performance issues in MariaDB on Windows, they might consider switching to Linux to see if it fixes their problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if these are relevant; they come from the Changelogs:

----- 2017-05-23 MariaDB 10.2.6 -- -- -----

Bug #23046302 COUNT(*) MUCH SLOWER ON 5.7 THAN 5.6

----- 2017-04-10 5.7.18 General Availability -- Bugs Fixed -- InnoDB -----

SELECT COUNT(*) performance regressed in some cases due to a modification introduced in MySQL 5.7.2 that caused InnoDB to count rows by traversing the clustered index instead of a smaller secondary index. The modification was reverted. (Bug #23046302, Bug #80580)

----- 2017-04-10 5.7.18 General Availability -- Bugs Fixed -- -----

EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_name could incorrectly report an Extra value of Select tables optimized away due to a modification introduced in MySQL 5.7.2 that caused InnoDB to count rows by traversing the clustered index instead of a smaller secondary index. The Extra value now displays Count Rows. (Bug #24337385, Bug #82313)